# Fragmentation Layout inflater issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

hello guys..
            i want to add two  layout in my fragmentation .one layout already inflated after that second layout inflate on first layout button click...well i tried to  remove first layout on button click of first layout button  and inflate second layout but my button click does not response any type of reaction..please help me

```
  public static LinearLayout mLL_MyNotes,mLin_myNotes,mLL_UploadNotes;
  public static ViewFlipper mVF_MyNotes,mViewUploadMyNotes;
  public static View mViewMyNotes;

   @Override
     public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
     text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     text.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
     text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);


    if(mContent.equalsIgnoreCase("My Notes")){

        mViewMyNotes = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_myspace_mynotes_list, container, false);

        mLin_myNotes=(LinearLayout)mViewMyNotes.findViewById(R.id.mainLin_MyNotes);

        mVF_MyNotes = (ViewFlipper) mViewMyNotes.findViewById(R.id.vf_MySpace_MyNotes);

        mbtn_Upload_MyNotes = (Button) mViewMyNotes.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload_MySpace_MyNotes);
        mWV_MyNotes = (WebView) mViewMyNotes.findViewById(R.id.wv_MySpace_MyNotes);

        mLV_MyNotes = (ListView) mViewMyNotes.findViewById(R.id.lv_MySpace_MyNotes);
        mLV_MyNotes.setAdapter(new MySpace_MyNotesAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.activity_myspace_mynotes_listitem));

        mbtn_Upload_MyNotes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater Newinflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

          mViewUploadMyNotes==Newinflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_myspace_mynotes_uploades,null);          
                  mLL_UploadNotes = (LinearLayout) mViewUploadMyNotes.findViewById(R.id.llUpload_MyNotes);

                ((ViewGroup) mLin_myNotes.getParent()).removeView(mViewUploadMyNotes);

                mLin_myNotes.addView(mViewUploadMyNotes);

            }
        });
        return mViewMyNotes;
```

Comment: no body understand my problem!!!!

Comment: Hi.. Your problem is you cant click on the button which is in fragment layout..? right..?

Comment: Put the Debugger point at the If condition and check that condition becomes tue and debugger poing goes inside the debugger point.

Comment: hey sulabha thnks for ur nice suggestion..my problem has been solved

Comment: You can point up my comment if is helpfully to you.

Comment: ya sure why not......